# Sandbox account to test 'Sign in with Apple'

Tags: ios, swift3

Should we set-up a sandbox account to test 'Sign in with Apple'?
If yes, how can I set-up one?
Can I use the existing sandbox tester account ID to test 'sign-in with apple'?